# RSpec - Testing that a nested association is also saved on a create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations, factory-bot, nested-attributes

```
let(:user_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user) }
let(:account_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:account, owner_attributes: user_attributes) }

describe "success" do
  it 'saves the account and user to the database' do
    results = expect { post :create, account: account_attributes }
    results.to change { Account.count }.by( 1 )
    results.to change { User.count }.by( 1 )
  end
end
```

The Account.count passes, but the User.count fails. Works just fine in the browser. Can't find any documentation anywhere about testing that an associated/nested object is also saved on a create action.

Comment: Edited above for clarity and to separate them out. Account.count goes up by one, but User.count does not go up by one.

Comment: Please post the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a debug statement in the controller and see whats happening when you run the test. If you are using ruby > 1.9, use the gem byebug. Put byebug on line 1 of AccountsController.create and then see what is happening.